# XSLT 3.0 xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"

Tags: xslt

I'd like to filter XML elements out of a response with XSLT 3 with Saxon HE 10.6

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>10.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I saved cases on https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Pc and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Pc/1

I was hoping to be able to use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />
```

(that is: skip elements the do not match a filter.)

So I want to copy all elements that match some deeper attribute value

The structure is like a dataset of shoes with a status, appearing like generic items on a bill.

bill.xml

```
  <bill>
    <item>
      <shoes>
        <status>0</status>
      </shoes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <shoes>
        <status>1</status>
      </shoes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <shoes>
        <status>2</status>
      </shoes>
    </item>
  </bill>
```

I want the generic items (of any kind (shoes)) with status=0

(otherwise said: skip items where '*/[status=0'] does not match)

bill.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />
  <xsl:template match="item/*[status=0]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result would have to be

```
<bill>
  <item>
    <shoes><status>0</status></shoes>
  </item>
</bill>
```

Alas, this script finds nothing

But. In the case of

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```

It finds (as expected) all items that are not status=0

```
<bill>
  <item/>
  <item>
    <shoes><status>1</status></shoes>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shoes><status>2</status></shoes>
  </item>
</bill>
```

If i use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-copy" />
```

It finds all of the items (no filtering).

It seems not very logical to me, even though an item element has the context.

I use SAXON HE version 10.6, the only difference in the code with javax.xml.transform is the use of

```
TransformerFactory factory = new **BasicTransformerFactory**();
```

Question is how to make an elegant small script that does this: output the whole xml, skipping the items that do not match.

Comment: What is the exact result that you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with `<xsl:template match="item[not(*/status = 0)]"/>` (or `<xsl:template match="item/*[not(status = 0)]"/>` if the `item` elements all need to be copied, only their children need to be filtered)).

I am not sure where you got the idea that `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />` should do unless you explicitly added `<xsl:template match="item[*/status = 0]"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`. Even then you would lose the root element.

If you look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-skip it says:

> The effect of processing a tree using a mode that specifies
> `on-no-match="shallow-skip"` is to drop both the textual content and the
> markup from the result document, except where there is an explicit
> user-written template rule that dictates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin

So the logic goes a bit further.

the tip to explicitly write the node misses out of the  root tag

```
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Pc/2
```

so the solution is to use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> 
<xsl:template match="item/*[not(status = 0)]"/>
```

see

```
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Pc/3
```

Michael's suggestion with on-no-match="shallow-skip" also works including the root tag, diving into a descendant.

```
<xsl:template match="*[descendant-or-self::status=0] | status[.=0]/text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Pc/4

The use of descendant-or-self is new to me though

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you (apparently) expect, while using:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />
```

as the default, you would have to make your template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[descendant-or-self::status=0] | status[.=0]/text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in order to copy all branches leading to a `<status>0</status>` leaf in their entirety.

---

As already noted, it is much simpler to make:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```

the default. Then you only need to add:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::status=0)]"/>
```

in order to suppress the branches not having a `<status>0</status>` leaf.